# Android release app requesting addTestDevice with admob?

Tags: android, admob

I have developed an app in Studio with admob integration. While developing on my own device I used the adTestDevice method. However now that I have completed the first release version and installed it on a friend's phone to try, it is still saying in logcat

> Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
>   to get test ads on this device.

Is this normal or am I missing something? Should it still be saying this? I ask because I had my account suspended once already.
I am generating a signed APK with 'release' build type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test device id you added earlier was for your device. Like you said now you are running the app on your friend's device. This new device has a different test device id. If you want to receive test ads there too you'll need to add that one separately as a test device.

Each device has a distinct id (which is nothing but its mac address in case of android) which is to be used as the test device id in order to receive only test ads on that device.

Comment: Yes of course, I know this but what I'm not too sure about is whether I should still be getting the logcat prompt about addTestDevice for my friend's device

Comment: yes, that is normal. Google Play Service will log it for any device on which it renders an ad if it is not added as a test device.

Comment: does that answer your question?

Comment: So do I simply leave out the code `addTestDevice("xxx")` for a release version?

Comment: Doesn't matter if you leave it there... It's just your device... In fact it is safe in case you accidentally click an ad later...